# Error when playing large videofile with react-native-video

Tags: react-native, filesize, react-native-video

Im building an app with react-native and are trying to run a videofile that is 1.2 Gb in filesize but Im getting errormessage:

> Error: Cannot create a string longer than 0x3fffffe7 characters

I think this is because of the filesize. If I run a videofile in smaller size it works fine.

Here is the code to my component:

```
const Video = () => {
    const myFile = require('../assets/myVideo.mp4');

    return (
        <Fragment>
            <View>
                <Video
                    repeat={true}
                    source={myFile}
                    ref={(ref) => {
                        video = ref
                    }}
                    onBuffer={this.onBuffer}
                    onError={this.videoError}
                    rate={1}
                />
            </View>
        </Fragment>
    );
}

export default Video;
```

How can I get around this? I have also tried to stream it using the uri below but Im not sure if I didnt got the syntax right because nothing happened :) and got this errormessage:

> E/MediaPlayer: Error (1,-2147483648)

```
<Video
   repeat={true}
   paused={!bgPaused}             
   source={{ uri: 'file:///Users/myAccount/myVideo.mp4' }}
   ref={(ref) => {
      fullscreenVideo = ref
   }}
   onBuffer={this.onBuffer}
   onError={this.videoError}
   style={styles.backgroundVideo}
   rate={1}
/>
```

Comment: Your app will need to request permission to read external storage if you're accessing a file outside your app.

Comment: Well its in the assets folder inside the app I guess. But if that is not the case how do I request permission?

Comment: Your cell phone doesn't know the location of your MacFolder. Your access to the route seems wrong.

Comment: At least it works with smaller files:     const myFile = require('../assets/myVideo.mp4');

Comment: The path I am talking about is not a project file path. External path. For example, mobile phone internal files

Comment: ok. so have you got any suggestion of further investigate this? Im sorry but Im not really following :)

Answer (score 0):

Would you try this one?

import myFile from "../assets/myVideo.mp4";

rather than below

const myFile = require('../assets/myVideo.mp4');

Hope it works but doesn't expect too much!

Comment: Thanks! But it was the same error. The strange thing is that as soon as I put a large file in the asset folder the app fails to load. ´Error: Call retries were exceeded at ChildProcessWorker.initialize´   That is even if I dont call the file! I guess it might be since the file is to heavy to load into the memory? Any idea how to solve this is very much appreciated!

Comment: sorry @acroscene it exceeds my ability. I hope you find good solution.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to resolve it with a path supported by your current module, you can use two for each

**Platform : Android**

```js
source={{ uri: 'file:///sdcard/Movies/myVideo.mp4' }}
```

> Note: Your app will need to request permission to read external
>   storage if you're accessing a file outside your app.

**Platforms: iOS**
Path to a sound file in your iTunes library. Typically shared from iTunes to your app.

```js
source={{ uri: 'ipod-library:///path/to/myVideo.mp3' }}
```

> Note: Using this feature adding an entry for
>   NSAppleMusicUsageDescription to your Info.plist file as described
>   [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/General/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/CocoaKeys.html)

If you don't want to use these two methods, there is a way to upload them to an external site and get the path to that file.